Appropriate way to correct for multiple hypotheses with multiple one-way ANOVAs and Tukey's post-hoc
I have a dataset with four groups and 14 different dependent variables. Based on the answer given here, I think the best approach for my analytical question is to perform multiple one-way ANOVAs, followed up with Tukey's tests for the dependent variables that showed significant ANOVAs.
My question is, how should I perform my multiple hypothesis corrections? It seems clear that I should apply a multiple hypothesis correction to the ANOVAs before deciding to run the post-hoc tests. When I run my Tukey's tests should the number of hypotheses I'm correcting for include the ANOVAs that were run?
To lay out an example:

I run my tests and find that 4 of my ANOVAs were significant after multiple hypothesis correction.
I then run 4 Tukey tests and obtain 6 p-values from each (for each unique pairwise comparison between groups). I'm using TukeyHSD in R, so the p-values it reports have already been adjusted for the multiple comparisons within each DV.

I have two basic questions:

Is it appropriate to apply a Benjamini-Hochberg correction to the p-values reported by TukeyHSD? Or is there another correction that's objectively more appropriate for this situation?
Regardless of the correction I'm using, should the number of hypotheses tested only include the post-hoc tests (24 p-values) or should it include the ANOVAs as well (24 + 14 = 38 p-values)?

Thank you!
